# NextJS not updating the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I got this error: Did not expect server HTML to contain the text node "Loading...". After fiddling with my code for a few seconds. I updated the component like this:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  return (<div>Hello</div>)
}
```

But even after that page `/dashboard` is still showing `Loading...` and the error message on console is still appearing. i tried restarting `npm run dev` and even deleted `.next` folder. I tried to use different browser. But the page is still not reflecting the latest changes. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The component was using a layout. And that was what was loading the `loading...` message.

Comment: If the problem isn't reproducible, you should close it for that reason instead of posting an answer saying so